# Problem installing microservices

Tags: web8.5, microservices

My environment is:

- Windows 2012 R2
- Java 8

Is a simple machine used for deployment and .NET presentation server.

I have the deployer-combined, discovery and content microservices configured and they start ok if I use the `.\start.ps1` in PowerShell, but whe I install the microservices as Windows Services they don't start and the only error I obtain is the the System Event Log:

[image: EventViewer System error]

> The SDL Web Content Service service terminated with the following
>   service specific error: Incorrect function

I think is a problem with the Java virtual machine, but it seems to be ok. It's a JRE 1.8.0_131. Do you think a JDK is needed?

Have any clues or ideas of what to check or try?

Comment: right click the any jar/dll and click on Property, do you see them in block state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error "incorrect function" is likely due to your Java installation being questionable (perhaps corrupted).

To verify to see if indeed this was caused by Java, do the below steps:

1. Go to `c:\windows\system32\LogFile\Apache`
2. There should be files with name starting as
   `commons-daemon.yyyy-mm-dd.log`, look up the latest log  (or try to
   restart the service so it generates a new log message)
3. Look in the log and see if you see some message like 'Failed creating java'
4. If you see such a message, then that's it. Your java installation
   is corrupted somewhere. If so, uninstall all java jre/jdks from the
   system and re-install.

Comment: I see the "Failed creating java" messages, and reinstalled the JRE, but the problem is still there. Not sure if it's the JVM, because the service can be started with ./start.ps1. But something related with the "procrun" which starts the jvm. Where can I see more information? any ideas?

Comment: Finally found that the JVM were 32 bit, and is needed a 64 bit version of the JVM.

Comment: @RaúlEscudero: Could you please post your comments in answer and accept it, so that it can use for other users

Answer (score 4):

Finally found that the JVM were 32 bit, and is needed a 64 bit version of the JVM.